# Regular expression that accepts strings where every two zeros are followed by a one

Tags: regex, automata

so i'm looking for a way to write a regex that accepts all strings, but in any string that contains two consecutive zeros a 1 must follow immediately
for ex. it will accept

```
0
10
01
0010
1111
11001001
```

but not

```
00
000
100
```

Answer (score 2):

If we must have 00 followed by 1, this implies the following two things:

1. the substring 000 is not in the string
2. the string does not end with the suffix 00

It so happens that the above two conditions also imply that any instance of 00 must be followed by a 1; these conditions are equivalent. Giving the conditions separately will make it easier to solve this problem.

It is easy to write down a deterministic finite automaton for this language; something like this will suffice:

```
        /---1----\----1---\           /--\
        V        |        |           V   \
----->(q0)--0-->(q1)--0-->(q2)--0-->(q3)  0,1
      \  ^                             \---/
       \1/
```

States `(q0)` and `(q1)` are accepting and states `(q2)` and `(q3)` are not. `(q3)` is a dead state since any string with three 0s is not in our language by condition 1 and cannot be redeemed. `(q2)` is not a dead state since we can fix this string by adding a `1` to the end.

With a DFA in hand, we can apply known algorithms to produce a regular expression. We can write down a system:

```
(q0) = e + (q0)1 + (q1)1 + (q2)1
(q1) = (q0)0
(q2) = (q1)0
(q3) = (q2)0 + (q3)(0 + 1)
```

Now we want to solve for `(q0)` and `(q1)` and our regular expression will be the union (`+`) of these two expressions. We can ignore `(q3)` since it's not needed and use substitution:

```
(q0) = e + (q0)1 + (q0)01 + (q2)1
(q1) = (q0)0
(q2) = (q0)00

(q0) = e + (q0)1 + (q0)01 + (q0)001
(q1) = (q0)0
(q2) = (q0)00

(q0) = e + (q0)(1 + 01 + 001)
(q1) = (q0)0
(q2) = (q0)00

(q0) = (1 + 01 + 001)*
(q1) = (1 + 01 + 001)*0
(q2) = (1 + 01 + 001)*00
```

So, our answer is `(1 + 01 + 001)* + (1 + 01 + 001)*0 = (1 + 01 + 001)*(e + 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of nested [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
^(?!.*00(?!1)).*
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Anchor the regex to the start of the string
(?!    # Assert that it's impossible to match
 .*    #  any string (caveat: if your string might contain newlines, you need the (?s) modifier)
 00    #  followed by 00
 (?!1) #  unless that is followed by 1
)      # End of lookahead
.*     # This matches the actual string (if the previous lookahead was successful)
       # The .* can be omitted (but then the successful matches will return an empty string)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Q1lppq/1).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the regex flavor of automata, but something like

```
^.*001.*$
```

would match

```
0- 10- 01- 0010- 1111- 11001001- #match
00- 000- 100 #no match
001- 000- 100 #match
00- 000- 1001 #match
```

Explanation

- `^` match start of line
- `.*` match any char between zero and infinite times
- `001` match literal 001
- `.*` match any char between zero and infinite times
- `$` match end of line

Comment: This does not do what the author wants. Finding a 001 is not the requirement but rejecting strings that contain 00 not followed by 1.

Comment: Appreciate the downvote comment. I misunderstood the question